# MongoDb - Regex for Number

Tags: regex, mongodb

Mongo collection :

```
{
    "price" : 120, // Type : Number
    "name" : "Product Name 1",
    "productId" : "num01",
}
{
    "price" : 121,
    "name" : "Product Name 2",
    "productId" : "num02",
}
{
    "price" : 50,
    "name" : "Product Name 3",
    "productId" : "num03",
}
```

I'm using regex to search for `name`& `productId` :

```
var searchText = new RegExp(req.body.search.value, "i");
Product
    .find({
        "companyId" : req.params.companyId , 
        "isDeleted" : false,
        $or : [
                { "name"      : searchText },
                { "productId" : searchText }
            ]
    })
```

How can I search for price field, if input is `12` product 1,2 will be selected.

Comment: You mean the first (`price: 120`) and second (`price: 121`) products match? This is because these both contain `12` followed by anything, which you do not exclude in you expression. If you must use regexp, consider looking for the _exact_ pattern, e.g. `^12$` ("from begin to end I expect `12`"). For numbers it will often be more convenient to search within ranges using `$gt`, `$gte`, `$lt`, `$lte`, etc

Answer (score -2):

You are expecting a SQL like command to be executed against price.

By having numbers for price we will not be able to do that, so change your data  to string

```
{
    "price" : "120", // Type : String
    "name" : "Product Name 1",
    "productId" : "num01",
}
{
    "price" : "121",
    "name" : "Product Name 2",
    "productId" : "num02",
}
{
    "price" : "50",
    "name" : "Product Name 3",
    "productId" : "num03",
}
```

then you can use like command by giving regex

sample queries
db.yourcollectionname.find({price: /12/})

db.yourcollectionname.find({price: /^12/})